# logic app foreach - variable body?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have an action called Get_row which outputs "Package1Id" and "Package2Id" values. I want to use a foreach loop to access these values as shown below:

```
"parameters": {
   "packages": {
     "type": "array",
     "defaultValue": "\"[ \"Package1\", \"Package2\" ]\""
   }
}

"forEach_package": {
  "type": "foreach",
  "foreach": "[parameters('packages')]",
  "actions": {
    "process_package": {
      "type": "Compose",
      "inputs": {
        "what": "@{body('Get_row')?[coalesce(item(), 'Id')]}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So the "what" values should essentially be:

```
"what": "@{body('Get_row')?['Package1Id']}"
"what": "@{body('Get_row')?['Package2Id']}"
```

I cannot seem to get it to work or find any examples anywhere. 
Any ideas if I can do this?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your "foreach" property. In order to reference a parameter value, you should use the @parameters() function, like below

```
"foreach": "@parameters('packages')"
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/definition-language for details (under the 'expressions' section)

Comment: "foreach": "[parameters('packages')]" works just fine, that's not the issue but thanks for helping out. I did try your suggestion but that failed.